# How to Crop the detected object using Yolo model and save image using Python?

Tags: object, save, yolo

I am detecting a single object (LCD screen) using YOLO model and it detects the target object successfully and save the output image with the bounding box. but i want to crop only the detected regions (LCD) and save it (crop detected LCD). Where i should make changes in the YOLO files? I do not know too much about backend files.

I tried to detect the LCD using OpenCV, but not in Yolo.

Comment: From the outputs of yolo, you should be able to have the bounding boxes. Then, with the original image, you can crop the corresponding subregion. Can you be more specific in your problem, providing for example a [mcve]

Comment: I mean, that's his request isn't it? He *wants* a minimal reproductible example lol. Also, can you clarify where in the "outputs of yolo" we can find the bounding boxes?

Comment: @xiawi gmelodie    I have made few changes in the   image.c  file in the YOLO project which handles the image operations.  It resolved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share those changes?

Comment: @FrederikBrammer You can try to make changes as they suggested in the github repo and then run the demo.
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/954